# Why Complete LinkedList Reversed?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, linked-list

**For Input  1->2->2->4->5->6->7->8**

**My output is 8 7 6 5 4 2 2 1 but I don't know why?**

**LINK OF PROBLEM IS BELOW :**
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reverse-a-linked-list-in-groups-of-given-size/1

## **Reverse a Linked List in groups of given size.**

Given a linked list of size **N**. The task is to reverse every **k** nodes (where k is an input to the function) in the linked list. If the number of nodes is not a multiple of *k* then left-out nodes, in the end, should be considered as a group and must be reversed (See Example 2 for clarification).

**Example 1:**

```
Input:
LinkedList: 1->2->2->4->5->6->7->8
K = 4
Output: 4 2 2 1 8 7 6 5 
Explanation: 
The first 4 elements 1,2,2,4 are reversed first 
and then the next 4 elements 5,6,7,8. Hence, the 
resultant linked list is 4->2->2->1->8->7->6->5.
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input:
LinkedList: 1->2->3->4->5
K = 3
Output: 3 2 1 5 4 
Explanation: 
The first 3 elements are 1,2,3 are reversed 
first and then elements 4,5 are reversed.Hence, 
the resultant linked list is 3->2->1->5->4.
```

**Your Task:**
You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function **reverse**() which should reverse the linked list in group of size **k** and return the head of the modified linked list.

**Expected Time Complexity** : O(N)
**Expected Auxilliary Space** : O(1)

Constraints:

1 <= N <= 10<sup>4</sup>
1 <= k <= N

MY CODE BELOW:

```
//{ Driver Code Starts
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
    
    node(int x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
    
};

/* Function to print linked list */
void printList(struct node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


// } Driver Code Ends
/*
  Reverse a linked list
  The input list will have at least one element  
  Return the node which points to the head of the new LinkedList
  Node is defined as 
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node* next;
    
        node(int x){
            data = x;
            next = NULL;
        }
    
    }*head;
*/

class Solution
{
     node* reverseHelper(node* head){
          node* pre = NULL;
          node* curr = head;
          
         while(curr!=NULL){
           node* nextTocurr = curr->next;
           curr->next = pre;
           pre = curr;
           curr = nextTocurr;
         } 
         return pre;
    }
     
    public:
    struct node *reverse (struct node *head, int k)
    { 
        // Complete this method
        if(head==NULL|| head->next==NULL){
            return head;
        }
        
        int count = 0;
        node* tail = head;
        
        while(count<k || tail->next!=NULL){
            tail = tail->next;
            count++;
        }
          node* head2 = tail->next;
          tail->next = NULL;
        
         node* ans = reverseHelper(head); 
         head->next = reverse(head2,k);
         return ans;
        }
        
};


//{ Driver Code Starts.

/* Drier program to test above function*/
int main(void)
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
     
    while(t--)
    {
        struct node* head = NULL;
        struct node* temp = NULL;
        int n;
        cin >> n;
         
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            if(i == 0)
            {
                head = new node(value);
                temp = head;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next = new node(value);
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        
        Solution ob;
        head = ob.reverse(head, k);
        printList(head);
    }
     
    return(0);
}


// } Driver Code Ends
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this loop:

```
 int count = 0;
 while(count<k || tail->next!=NULL){
```

It has two issues:

- The loop will continue until the end of the list because the second condition will be true until that end is reached. The logical OR (`||`) should be a logical AND (`&&`), because you want **both** conditions to be true, not just one.
- When the previous point is corrected, the loop will still iterate one time too many, because the `head` node was already considered to be included in the "slice". Correct by initialising `count=1`.

With those two corrections your code will work as intended.